# MVC3 Html editor helpers display old model value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

After form submit Html editor helpers (TextBox, Editor, TextArea) display old value not a current value of model.text

Display helpers (Display, DisplayText) display proper value.

*Is there any way editor helpers to display current model.text value?*

**Model**

```
namespace TestProject.Models
{
  public class FormField
  {
    public string text { get;set; }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace TestProject.Controllers
{
  public class FormFieldController : Controller
  {
     public ActionResult Index (Models.FormField model=null)
     {
       model.text += "_changed";
       return View(model);
     }
  }
}
```

**View**

```
@model TestProject.Models.FormField
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
  <div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.text)
  </div>
  <div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.text)
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering hidden form field using @Html.HiddenFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755323/rendering-hidden-form-field-using-html-hiddenfor)

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form to an MVC action the values of the input fields are recovered from *the POSTEd values available in the form and not from the model*. That makes sense right? We don't want the user to show a different value in a textbox than they have just entered and submitted to the server.

If you want to show the updated model to the user then you should have another action and from the post action you have to redirect to that action.

Basically you should have two actions one action that renders the view to edit the model and another one saves the model to database or whatever and redirect the request to the former action.

An example:

```
public class FormFieldController : Controller
{
    // action returns a view to edit the model
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
      var model = .. get from db based on id
      return View(model);
    }

    // action saves the updated model and redirects to the above action
    // again for editing the model
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(SomeModel model)
    {
       // save to db
       return RedirectToAction("Edit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using HTML editors such as HTML.EditorFor() or HTML.DisplayFor(), if you attempt to modify or change the model values in the controller action you won't see any change unless you remove the ModelState for the model property you want to change.

While @Mark is correct, you don't *have* to have a separate controller action (but you usually would want to) and you don't need to redirect to the original action.

e.g. - call ModelState.Remove(*modelPropertyName*)...

```
public ActionResult Index (Models.FormField model=null)
 {
   ModelState.Remove("text");
   model.text += "_changed";
   return View(model);
 }
```

And if you want to have separate actions for GET and POST (recommended) you can do...

```
public ActionResult Index ()
 {
   Models.FormField model = new Models.FormField();  // or get from database etc.

   // set up your model defaults, etc. here if needed

   return View(model);
 }

[HttpPost]  // Attribute means this action method will be used when the form is posted
public ActionResult Index (Models.FormField model)
 {
   // Validate your model etc. here if needed ...

   ModelState.Remove("text"); // Remove the ModelState so that Html Editors etc. will update

   model.text += "_changed";  // Make any changes we want

   return View(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problem, I hope I can help others have similar problem:

`ActionExecutingContext` has `Controller.ViewData`.
as you can see:

```
new ActionExecutingContext().Controller.ViewData
```

This ViewData contains `ModelState` and `Model`. The ModelState shows the state of model has passed to controller for example. When you have an error on `ModelState` the unacceptable `Model` and its state passed to View. So you will see the old value, yet. Then you have to change the Model value of ModelState manually.
for example for clearing a data:

```
  ModelState.SetModelValue("MyDateTime", new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Also you can manipulate the ViewData, as [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc).
The `EditorFor`, `DisplayFor()` and etc, use this `ViewData` contents.